# Spring boot: accessing command line args from a bean

Tags: java, spring-boot, properties

I run spring boot application with a single argument - filename. The file contains some properties I need in runtime.
When the application starts it checks if `args.length==1`

But I need this file (properties) in a single point - `@Component` annotated bean.

Is it a way to get an access to the file's content from it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Spring, there is a bean called [ApplicationArguments](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/ApplicationArguments.html) that provides access to the arguments used to run an application.

```
@Component
public MyComponent {
    @Autowired
    private ApplicationArguments  applicationArguments;

    public void method() {
        List<String> filenameArgs = applicationArguments.getOptionValues("filename")
    }
}
```

Comment: Everything works if reffer to ApplicationArguments in regular method. But when i use it at init (@PostConstruct), I get NullPointerException